# How to avoid storing passwords in the clear for tomcat's server.xml Resource definition of a DataSource?

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, configuration

The resource definition in tomcat's `server.xml` looks something like this...

```xml
<Resource
    name="jdbc/tox"
    scope="Shareable"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@yourDBserver.yourCompany.com:1521:yourDBsid"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
    username="tox"
    password="toxbaby"
    maxIdle="3"
    maxActive="10"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    validationQuery="select * from dual"
    logAbandoned="true"
    debug="99"/>
```

The password is in the clear.  How to avoid this?

Answer (score 42):

As said before encrypting passwords is just moving the problem somewhere else.

Anyway, it's quite simple.
Just write a class with static fields for your secret key and so on, and static methods to encrypt, decrypt your passwords.
Encrypt your password in Tomcat's configuration file (`server.xml` or `yourapp.xml`...) using this class.

And to decrypt the password "on the fly" in Tomcat, extend the DBCP's `BasicDataSourceFactory` and use this factory in your resource.

It will look like:

```xml
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/myDataSource"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="user"
        password="encryptedpassword"
        driverClassName="driverClass"
        factory="mypackage.MyCustomBasicDataSourceFactory"
        url="jdbc:blabla://..."/>
```

And for the custom factory:

```java
package mypackage;

....

public class MyCustomBasicDataSourceFactory extends org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory {

@Override
public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context nameCtx, Hashtable environment) throws Exception {
    Object o = super.getObjectInstance(obj, name, nameCtx, environment);
    if (o != null) {
        BasicDataSource ds = (BasicDataSource) o;
        if (ds.getPassword() != null && ds.getPassword().length() > 0) {
            String pwd = MyPasswordUtilClass.unscramblePassword(ds.getPassword());
            ds.setPassword(pwd);
        }
        return ds;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: To me, this doesn't add any security, because the attacker can always decompile your jar to get the password you hardcoded in the class file...

Comment: IMO it is still better than having the password in the clear where every dumb script kiddie will know to look for it. It raises the bar some, doesn't it ?

Comment: @dmansfield - Am I missing something? I do not see where the password would be hard-coded in any class file in the above approach?

Comment: @AjoyBhatia - How does MyPasswordUtilClass.unscramblePassword(String s) do the unscrambling? It must have a secret available to do the unscrambling, or even worse, use a non-keyed algorithm (e.g. rot13) to unscramble. So really this just pushes the problem to the MyPasswordUtilClass - where does the secret come from?

Comment: you could read the password from an external file which is only readable by the user under which tomcat runs (while still keeping it separate from the rest of the configuration)

Comment: @AndreHolzner Having a separate file only readable by tomcat that contains a readable password to decrypt the credentials in context.xml is not at all more secure than having readable credentials in context.xml if the latter is also only readable by tomcat. Both would be compromised by the exact same conditions. It is, however, a lot more cumbersome to the administrators and developers. What you're describing is addressed by the first sentence in this answer.

Answer (score 12):

Tomcat has [a Password FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Password) that specifically addresses your question. In short: Keep the password in the clear and properly lock-down your server.

That page also offers some suggestions of how security-by-obscurity might be used to pass an auditor's checklist.

Comment: Still, one may want to keep a file containing the password separately from the rest of the configuration. In some cases one wants to put configuration files into some revision control system which is readable to all involved developers and not only to the system administrators.

Comment: That barely addresses anything. I cannot commit a config file to version control with passwords in it, but context.xml needs to be the same on all deployments, so their "auditor" is a straw man.

Comment: fyi: I've taken the liberty to update the FAQ link to the new location

Answer (score 5):

As @Ryan mentioned, please read Tomcat's [Tomcat Password FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Password) before implementing this solution.  You are only adding obscurity not security.

@Jerome Delattre's answer will work for simple JDBC data sources, but not for more complicated ones that connect as part of the datasource construction (e.g. oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource).

This is alternative approach that modifies the password prior to calling the existing factory.  Below is an example of a factory for a basic datasource and one for an Atomikos JTA compatible XA datasource.

Basic Example:

```
public class MyEncryptedPasswordFactory extends BasicDataSourceFactory {

    @Override
    public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context context, Hashtable<?, ?> environment)
            throws Exception {
        if (obj instanceof Reference) {
            Reference ref = (Reference) obj;
            DecryptPasswordUtil.replacePasswordWithDecrypted(ref, "password");
            return super.getObjectInstance(obj, name, context, environment);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Expecting javax.naming.Reference as object type not " + obj.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Atomikos Example:

```
public class MyEncryptedAtomikosPasswordFactory extends EnhancedTomcatAtomikosBeanFactory {
    @Override
    public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context context, Hashtable<?, ?> environment)
            throws NamingException {
        if (obj instanceof Reference) {
            Reference ref = (Reference) obj;
            DecryptPasswordUtil.replacePasswordWithDecrypted(ref, "xaProperties.password");
            return super.getObjectInstance(obj, name, context, environment);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Expecting javax.naming.Reference as object type not " + obj.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Updating password value in Reference:

```
public class DecryptPasswordUtil {

    public static void replacePasswordWithDecrypted(Reference reference, String passwordKey) {
        if(reference == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Reference object must not be null");
        }

        // Search for password addr and replace with decrypted
        for (int i = 0; i < reference.size(); i++) {
            RefAddr addr = reference.get(i);
            if (passwordKey.equals(addr.getType())) {
                if (addr.getContent() == null) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password must not be null for key " + passwordKey);
                }
                String decrypted = yourDecryptionMethod(addr.getContent().toString());
                reference.remove(i);
                reference.add(i, new StringRefAddr(passwordKey, decrypted));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once the .jar file containing these classes are in Tomcat's classpath  you can update your server.xml to use them.

```
<Resource factory="com.mycompany.MyEncryptedPasswordFactory" username="user" password="encryptedPassword" ...other options... />

<Resource factory="com.mycompany.MyEncryptedAtomikosPasswordFactory" type="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean" xaProperties.user="user" xaProperties.password="encryptedPassword" ...other options... />
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, whereas the previously suggested approach by Jerome did not (it threw an exception on the "super.getObjectInstance", which seemed to be trying to access the data source using the un-decrypted password).As a small addition, we are using a session DB as well as an application DB; I found that to allow password encryption for the session DB data source, we had to copy the jar containing the custom classes into the Tomcat /lib directory, as well as including them in the web apps, otherwise they were not accessible to the Tomcat session manager.

Comment: Correct.  You can put the driver files in a directory that we exposed to Tomcat using the catalina.properties file.

Comment: Do we have to add any Jars File in the Lib Folder for this?

Comment: @greencheese You don't have to, if you make the dependency provided.

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat needs to know how to connect to the database, so it needs access to the plain text password. If the password in encrypted, Tomcat needs to know how to decrypt it, so you are only moving the problem somewhere else.

The real problem is: who can access `server.xml` except for Tomcat? A solution is to give read access to `server.xml` only to root user, requiring that Tomcat is started with root privileges: if a malicious user gains root privileges on the system, losing a database password is probably a minor concern.

Otherwise you should type the password manually at every startup, but this is seldom a viable option.

Comment: I'm not by far a security expert, but it seems to me that Tomcat itself is one of the likely entrance doors for an attack (by a vulnerability exploit of Tomcat itself or of one of the librairies used by the app, such as the recent problems with Struts 2) and as such should not be given root privilege !?

Comment: I agree. I'm not using Tomcat anymore, but I would suggest to run it without root privileges.
Anyway, who can read tomcat directory, can read the DB password. As far as I know, this is an unavoidable problem with any language/framework you are using.

Comment: This is such a poor answer, why the up-votes boggles my mind. Keep things secure. Yes, encrypt passwords if you can and NO you don't have to run tomcat as root (not only is that bad, but the statement makes a false assumption that you have to). And gaining access to a system, losing a password or having it easily discovered is a MAJOR concern as the hack may not be detected for some time and your DB may contain sensitive data. A database is the GEM on the system and a main reason why someone would attempt to hack your box.

Comment: Giving read access to server.xml only to root user is such a bad practice. Instead, a new user should be created with the minimum privileges needed to run Tomcat. This user should ONLY be able to start/stop the server. Give read permissions for all config files only to this user. Then, disable directly logging on to the machine as that user.

Answer (score 2):

After 4 hours of work, search questions and answers I got the solution.
Based on the answer by @Jerome Delattre here is the complete code (with the JNDI Data source configuration).

Context.xml

```
<Resource
    name="jdbc/myDataSource"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    username="user"
    password="encryptedpassword"
    driverClassName="driverClass"
    factory="mypackage.MyCustomBasicDataSourceFactory"
    url="jdbc:blabla://..."/>
```

Custom Data Source Factory:

```
package mypackage;

public class MyCustomBasicDataSourceFactory extends org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory {
    @Override
    public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context nameCtx, Hashtable environment) throws Exception {
        Object o = super.getObjectInstance(obj, name, nameCtx, environment);
        if (o != null) {
            BasicDataSource ds = (BasicDataSource) o;
            if (ds.getPassword() != null && ds.getPassword().length() > 0) {
                String pwd = MyPasswordUtilClass.unscramblePassword(ds.getPassword());
                ds.setPassword(pwd);
            }
            return ds;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Data source bean:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSource ds = null;
    JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();
    try {
        ds = jndi.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource", DataSource.class);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        log.error("NamingException for java:comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource", e);
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: Is this the only way? Is it possible it may depend on the DB vendor?

Comment: @DavidBrossard nop, I use the same code over postgresql and sql server and works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**

You can use **WinDPAPI** to encrypt and decrypt data

```
public class MyDataSourceFactory extends DataSourceFactory{

private static WinDPAPI winDPAPI;

protected static final String DATA_SOURCE_FACTORY_PROP_PASSWORD = "password";

@Override
public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context nameCtx, Hashtable environment) throws Exception{

    Reference ref = (Reference) obj;
    for (int i = 0; i < ref.size(); i++) {
        RefAddr ra = ref.get(i);
        if (ra.getType().equals(DATA_SOURCE_FACTORY_PROP_PASSWORD)) {

            if (ra.getContent() != null && ra.getContent().toString().length() > 0) {
                String pwd = getUnprotectedData(ra.getContent().toString());
                ref.remove(i);
                ref.add(i, new StringRefAddr(DATA_SOURCE_FACTORY_PROP_PASSWORD, pwd));
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    return super.getObjectInstance(obj, name, nameCtx, environment);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**: As pointed out, encrypting credentials in context.xml while storing the decryption key in the next file over is literally only moving the problem. Since the user accessing context.xml will also need access to the decryption key, all credentials are still compromised if the application or the OS user is compromised.

**Solution**: The only solution that would add security is one that completely removes the decryption key from the entire setup. This could be achieved by requiring someone to type a password in your application on startup which is then used to decrypt all credentials.

**Further deferral of solution**: In most cases, such a password would likely need to be known by a number of administrators and/or developers. By using a password sharing solution that allows sharing of passwords (e.g. 1Password), the security is then deferred to each admin/dev's individual master password used to unlock his personal password vault.

**Possible degradation of solution/sarcasm**: With this setup, the worst case scenario would be that someone would simply keep their master password on a sticky note attached to a monitor. Whether that is more secure than having the decryption key in a file next to encrypted values should probably be a separate SO question or maybe a future study.

Answer (score -3):

All of the foregoing having been said, if you still want to avoid plain text passwords you can use a hashing algorithm such as SHA-256 or (preferably) SHA-512. When a password is created, obtain the hashed value and store it rather than the password. When a user logs in, hash the password and see of it matches the stored hashed password.
Hashing algorithms take a character string (or number) from a small string (or number) space into a much larger one in a way that is expensive to reverse.

Comment: that's completely useless for a database connection

Comment: Your solution describes a general solution for storing password in any system requiring authentication - like a database. The database itself is probably already doing this internally. What the OP is asking for is a way to store the password in a non clear text way in the tomcat config that enables Tomcat to authenticate the database connection using that password.

Answer (score -9):

We use C#'s    SHA1CryptoServiceProvider

```
print(SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sHA1Hasher = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();

        byte[] arrbytHashValue = sHA1Hasher.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes(clearTextPW));
        string HashData = System.BitConverter.ToString(arrbytHashValue);
        HashData = HashData.Replace("-", "");
        if (HashData == databaseHashedPassWO)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        });
```

)

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with tomcat config files.