# Securing password in tomcat server.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, password-protection

to secure the Password in Server.xml file I have encrypted the Password inside it and overreided the org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol: like the following:

The Server.xml look like this:

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/HasanDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxTotal="10" maxIdle="15" minIdle="3" initialSize="2" maxWaitMillis="10000"
              removeAbondend="true" removeAbondendTimeout="300"
              username="hasan" password="<encryptedpass>" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HasanDB"/>

package hasan;
public class Http11Nio2Protocol extends org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol  {
    @Override
    public void setKeystorePass(String certificateKeystorePassword) {
        try {
            System.out.println("..............===============certificateKeystorePassword===========................");
            super.setKeystorePass(EncryptService.decrypt(certificateKeystorePassword));
        } catch (final Exception e){
            super.setKeystorePass("");
        }
    }
}

package hasan;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class EncryptService {
    private static SecretKeySpec createSecretKey(char[] password, byte[] salt, int iterationCount, int keyLength) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
        PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterationCount, keyLength);
        SecretKey keyTmp = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
        return new SecretKeySpec(keyTmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
    }
    private static byte[] base64Decode(String property) throws IOException {
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(property);
    }
    static String decrypt(String string) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        String password = "password";
        byte[] salt = new String("salt").getBytes();
        int iterationCount = 100;
        int keyLength = 128;
        SecretKeySpec key = createSecretKey(password.toCharArray(),
                salt, iterationCount, keyLength);
        String iv = string.split(":")[0];
        String property = string.split(":")[1];
        Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        pbeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(base64Decode(iv)));
        return new String(pbeCipher.doFinal(base64Decode(property)), "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

I have put the Jar file of the above Code in tomcat_home/lib Folder.

When I run the tomcat 8.5 Server the method setKeystorePass in the above Code does not execute.

What must I do in order to make it OK?

Comment: You may find this interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129160/how-to-avoid-storing-passwords-in-the-clear-for-tomcats-server-xml-resource-def?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Configure Your Datasource**

```
<Resource name="jdbc/yourDB" 
auth="Container" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
factory="org.junjun.util.secured.resources.datasource.EncryptedDataSourceFactory"
url="e6nNC2NVXThPKSyKMvCiZTa4beL/BHxyu+188EeeNWq10ynepC2f4fXHzlKKdo9288uNOStZwa6Ztu0h7TrWVAJIrurKQkfO" 
username="PzyHPd4xkXJYvoN6ztoLWg==" 
password="zeBxd99nNw2Hg6f4g/Rt8PkB7+uHOwVD"
maxActive="20" 
maxIdle="10" 
maxWait="-1" />
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/yourDB" global="jdbc/yourDB" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</Context>
```

2. **Create Your Own Datasource Factory**

   package org.junjun.util.secured.resources.datasource;

   ```
   import java.util.Enumeration;
   import java.util.Hashtable;

   import javax.naming.Context;
   import javax.naming.Name;
   import javax.naming.RefAddr;
   import javax.naming.Reference;
   import javax.naming.StringRefAddr;

   import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory;
   import org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor;

   public class EncryptedDataSourceFactory extends BasicDataSourceFactory {

       private String USERNAME_TAG = "username";

       private String PASSWORD_TAG = "password";

       private String URL_TAG = "url";

       private StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();

       private String password = System.getenv("secret-key");

       public EncryptedDataSourceFactory() {
           encryptor.setPassword(this.password);
       }

       @Override
       public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context ctx, Hashtable env) throws Exception {
           if (obj instanceof Reference) {
               setUsername((Reference) obj);
               setPassword((Reference) obj);
               setURL((Reference) obj);
           }
           return super.getObjectInstance(obj, name, ctx, env);
       }

       private void setUsername(Reference ref) {
           findDecryptAndReplace(USERNAME_TAG, ref);
       }

       private void setPassword(Reference ref) {
           findDecryptAndReplace(PASSWORD_TAG, ref);
       }

       private void setURL(Reference ref) {
           findDecryptAndReplace(URL_TAG, ref);
       }

       private void findDecryptAndReplace(String refType, Reference ref) {
           Integer idx = find(refType, ref);
           if (idx == null) {
               System.out.println("The \"" + refType + "\" name/value pair was not found"
                       + " in the Reference object.  The reference Object is" + " " + ref.toString());
           } else {
               String decrypted = decrypt(ref.get(refType).getContent().toString());
               replace(idx, refType, decrypted, ref);
           }
       }

       private void replace(int idx, String refType, String newValue, Reference ref) {
           ref.remove(idx);
           ref.add(idx, new StringRefAddr(refType, newValue));
       }

       private String decrypt(String input) {
           return encryptor.decrypt(input);
       }

       private Integer find(String addrType, Reference ref) {
           Integer index = null;
           Enumeration<RefAddr> enu = ref.getAll();
           for (int i = 0; enu.hasMoreElements(); i++) {
               RefAddr addr = (RefAddr) enu.nextElement();
               if (addr.getType().compareTo(addrType) == 0)
                   index = i;
           }
           return index;
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Build Your Own Datasource Factory into a Jar File**
4. **Copy Jar Files to Tomcat**
5. **start Tomcat**