# Difference between 'dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory' and 'jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory'

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, server

Just to give slight background, I needed to encrypt the username/password fields of `server.xml`(TOMCAT) using the custom `DataSourceFactory` implementation.

There were many good answers and while some of them explained while extending 
    `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory` whereas some of the answers had   `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory` extended.

Some of the links I referred:

[How to avoid storing passwords in the clear for tomcat's server.xml Resource definition of a DataSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129160/how-to-avoid-storing-passwords-in-the-clear-for-tomcats-server-xml-resource-def)

https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/3624/Encrypt-username-and-password-for-JNDI-in-Tomcat-Server-xml.html

http://www.jdev.it/encrypting-passwords-in-tomcat/

So the question in my mind is what's the difference between the two and which one should be preferred when?

Comment: One observation I made while using the above two ways is while using the tomcat-jdbc technique with Sybase as database, I encountered the below exception:                    **java.sql.SQLException: The 'CREATE TABLE' command is not allowed within a multi-statement transaction in the 'tempdb' database :: SQL Error: 2762**. The exception gets resolved when I replaced the technique with tomcat-dbcp. I'm not aware of the reason though.