# How to provide security for database user name and password in java?

Tags: java, servlets

Currently, I am using the password as a plain text . I want to provide security.so I have been searching the internet to find solutions, many people are saying that

1. store a password in the environment variable.
2. use [*jasypt*](http://www.jasypt.org/) to encrypt/decrypt.

I am confusing about which one will provide security.
Please tell me which one is a better way and how to implement that one

Comment: Who do you want to protect against? Other developers on your team, anyone that breaches your server and retrieves the running jar, anyone who can extract live memory?

Comment: I can't see the password right now, so it surely is not *"visible to everyone"*.

Comment: Store the password wherever is best suited for your particular application. **Never** store a password in plain-text. Store passwords as a Hash which is non-decryptable (one way). There is only one person that should know what the actual password is and that is the User that created it. All your application needs to know is the hash for that password therefore, a generated hash is compared to the stored hash for password validity. If your application can actually decrypt a password....so can anyone else.

Comment: @DevilsHnd we are not talking about user passwords, but the password the application uses to connect to the db. You cannot hash that and there will almost always be more than one person who knows it.

Comment: At some point you have to store a password in plain text on a secured system. Otherwise you must encrypt the key used to encrypt the key used to encrypt the key used to encrypt the key… and Its [turtles all the way down](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down). See [this similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/129160/642706).