# Using encrypted password in database connection java ( jdbc / jndi )

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, jndi, tomcat8

I am using java 1.8, tomcat 8.5 and mysql 8

My aim to replace plain username and password with encrypted username and password for database connection.

The following is the database connection string:

```xml
<Resource name="jdbc/db" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000" username="encrypted_username" password="encrypted_password" driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rdbms" factory="abc.decrptAndReplace" />
```

The above works when I remove `factory` attribute and use plain username and password.

The below code is for `decrptAndReplace` Class

```java
package abc;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.Name;
import javax.naming.RefAddr;
import javax.naming.Reference;
import javax.naming.StringRefAddr;
import javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory;

public class decrptAndReplace implements ObjectFactory {

    public decrptAndReplace() {}

    @Override
    public Object getObjectInstance(final Object obj, final Name name, final Context nameCtx, final Hashtable environment) throws Exception {
        if (obj instanceof Reference) {
            setUsername((Reference) obj);
            setPassword((Reference) obj);
        }
        return this.getObjectInstance(obj, name, nameCtx, environment);
    }

    private void setUsername(final Reference ref) throws Exception {
        findDecryptAndReplace("username", ref);
    }

    private void setPassword(final Reference ref) throws Exception {
        findDecryptAndReplace("password", ref);
    }

    private void findDecryptAndReplace(final String refType, final Reference ref) throws Exception {
        final int idx = find(refType, ref);
        final String decrypted = decrypt(idx, ref);
        replace(idx, refType, decrypted, ref);
    }

    private void replace(final int idx, final String refType, final String newValue, final Reference ref) throws Exception {
        ref.remove(idx);
        ref.add(idx, new StringRefAddr(refType, newValue));
    }

    private String decrypt(final int idx, final Reference ref) throws Exception {
        return "plain_password/plain_username";
    }

    private int find(final String addrType, final Reference ref) throws Exception {
        final Enumeration enu = ref.getAll();
        for (int i = 0; enu.hasMoreElements(); i++) {
            final RefAddr addr = (RefAddr) enu.nextElement();
            if (addr.getType().compareTo(addrType) == 0) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        throw new Exception(ref.toString());
    }
}
```

And I am using receiving below error.

```
Unexpected exception resolving reference
```

I have read official documentation from below, but was disappointed.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Generic_JavaBean_Resources

Comment: Please, consider read [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129160/how-to-avoid-storing-passwords-in-the-clear-for-tomcats-server-xml-resource-def), I think it describes and address your problem.

Comment: isn't the problem that your find function crashes? You need to provide whole exception trace

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt that data at all?

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually implementing the javax.sql.DataSource interface as part of your decrptAndReplace class. Fix that and it should get rid of your error.